# How to wrap the delegate pattern with a one-shot publisher?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

Normally we can bridge our async code and Combine by wrapping our async code in a single-shot publisher using a `Future`:

```
func readEmail() -> AnyPublisher<[String], Error> {
  Future { promise in
    self.emailManager.readEmail() { result, error in
      if let error = error {
        promise(.failure(error))
      } else {
        promise(.success(result))
      }
    }
  }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

On the other hand, if we're wrapping the delegate pattern (instead of an async callback), it's [recommended to use a PassthroughSubject](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#patterns-delegate-publisher-subject), since the methods could be fired multiple times:

```
final class LocationHeadingProxy: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

  private let headingPublisher: PassthroughSubject<CLHeading, Error> 

  override init() {
    headingPublisher = PassthroughSubject<CLHeading, Error>()
    // ...
  }

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    headingPublisher.send(newHeading) 
  }
}
```

However, I'm trying to create a [one-shot publisher](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#reasoning-about-pipelines) which wraps an existing Delegate pattern. The reason is that I'm firing off a method like `connect()` and I expect either a success or failure to happen immediately. I do not want future updates to affect the pipeline.

For example, imagine I'm using `WKExtendedRuntimeSession` and wrapped the `.start()` method in `startSession()` below. If I have this wrapped successfully, I should be able to use it like so:

```
manager.startSession()
  .sink(
    receiveCompletion: { result in
      if result.isError {
        showFailureToStartScreen()
      }
    },
    receiveValue: { value in
      showStartedSessionScreen()
    })
  .store(in: &cancellables)
```

The reason a one-shot publisher is useful is because we expect one of the following two methods to be called soon after calling the method:

- Success: `extendedRuntimeSessionDidStart(_:)`
- Fail: `extendedRuntimeSession(_:didInvalidateWith:error:)`

Furthermore, when the session is halted (or we terminate it ourselves), we don't want side effects such as `showFailureToStartScreen()` to randomly happen. We want them to be handled explicitly elsewhere in the code. Therefore, having a one-shot pipeline is beneficial here so we can guarantee that `sink` is only called once.

---

I realize that one way to do this is to use a `Future`, store a reference to the `Promise`, and call the promise at a later time, but this seems hacky at best:

```
class Manager: NSObject, WKExtendedRuntimeSessionDelegate {
  var session: WKExtendedRuntimeSession?
  var tempPromise: Future<Void, Error>.Promise?

  func startSession() -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error> {
    session = WKExtendedRuntimeSession()
    session?.delegate = self
    return Future { promise in
      tempPromise = promise
      session?.start()
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }

  func extendedRuntimeSessionDidStart(_ extendedRuntimeSession: WKExtendedRuntimeSession) {
    tempPromise?(.success(()))
    tempPromise = nil
  }

  func extendedRuntimeSession(_ extendedRuntimeSession: WKExtendedRuntimeSession, didInvalidateWith reason: WKExtendedRuntimeSessionInvalidationReason, error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
      tempPromise?(.failure(error))
    }
    tempPromise = nil
  }
}
```

Is this really the most elegant way to work with delegates + one-shot publishers, or is there a more elegant way to do this in Combine?

---

For reference, [PromiseKit](https://mxcl.dev/PromiseKit/reference/v6/index.html) also has a similar API to `Future.init`. Namely, [`Promise.init(resolver:)`](https://mxcl.dev/PromiseKit/reference/v6/Classes/Promise.html#/s:10PromiseKit0A0C7pendingACyxG7promise_AA8ResolverCyxG8resolvertyFZ). However, PromiseKit also seems to natively support the functionality I describe above with their [`pending()`](https://mxcl.dev/PromiseKit/reference/v6/Classes/Promise.html#/s:10PromiseKit0A0C7pendingACyxG7promise_AA8ResolverCyxG8resolvertyFZ) function ([example](https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/swift-4-and-promisekit/)):

```
  func startSession() -> Promise {
    let (promise, resolver) = Promise.pending()
    tempPromiseResolver = resolver

    session = WKExtendedRuntimeSession()
    session?.delegate = self
    session?.start()

    return promise
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can ensure a one-shot publisher with `.first()` operator:

```
let subject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()

let publisher = subject.first()

let c = publisher.sink(receiveCompletion: {
    print($0)
}, receiveValue: {
    print($0)
})

subject.send(1)
subject.send(2)
```

The output would be:

```
1
finished
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be relevant for anyone interested:

```swift
import Combine
import GoogleCast

struct GCKRequestPublisher: Publisher {
    typealias Output = Void
    typealias Failure = Error

    let request: GCKRequest

    init(request: GCKRequest) {
        self.request = request
    }

    func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Self.Failure == S.Failure, Self.Output == S.Input {
        let subscription = GCKRequestSubscription(request: request, subscriber: subscriber)
        subscriber.receive(subscription: subscription)
    }
}

class GCKRequestSubscription<S: Subscriber>: NSObject, GCKRequestDelegate, Subscription where S.Input == Void, S.Failure == Error {
    var subscriber: S?
    let request: GCKRequest

    enum GCKRequestError: Error {
        case error(GCKError)
        case abort(GCKRequestAbortReason)
    }
    
    init(request: GCKRequest, subscriber: S) {
        self.subscriber = subscriber
        self.request = request
        super.init()
        self.request.delegate = self
    }

    func request(_ demand: Subscribers.Demand) { }

    func cancel() {
        request.cancel()
        subscriber = nil
    }

    // MARK: - GCKRequestDelegate
    func requestDidComplete(_ request: GCKRequest) {
        subscriber?.receive(completion: .finished)
    }

    func request(_ request: GCKRequest, didFailWithError error: GCKError) {
        subscriber?.receive(completion: .failure(GCKRequestError.error(error)))
    }

    func request(_ request: GCKRequest, didAbortWith abortReason: GCKRequestAbortReason) {
        subscriber?.receive(completion: .failure(GCKRequestError.abort(abortReason)))
    }
}
```